# display laravel array validation in javascript

Tags: arrays, laravel, validation, jquery-ajax

Can anyone please tell me how to display the validation error in javascript? I am sending the request with ajax and want to display the errors.

blade code

```
$('input[id^="facility_name"]').map(function() {
   return this.value;
}).get();
```

Laravel Validation

```
 'facility_name.*' => 'required|string|min:3|max:255',
```

display error from js

```
$('.facility_name_error').html(data.responseJSON.errors.facility_name);
or 
$('.facility_name_error').html(data.responseJSON.errors.facility_name[0]);
```

I attached the output of validation so how can I display this message to html

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your question is how can you access an object attribute with a dot (`.`) in the name, you can use the array way

```
data.responseJSON.errors['facility_name.0'][0]
```

Comment: thanku for help. Can you please give me an idea how can handle dynamic value  facility_name.0 facility_name.1 like this

Comment: For that you need to share more details (maybe in another question). Have you took a look to @ali answer? it's a more global way to handle all errors.

Answer (score 1):

you can access the error as the following:

in this example i will append the errors to li item you can do what you want

```
          $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'your-url',
            data: {your_data},
            success: function (data) {
           }
        }).fail(function (jqXhr) {
            var resp = jqXhr.responseJSON;
            if (jqXhr.status === 422) {
                var errorsHtml = '<ul>';
                $.each(resp.errors, function (key, value) {
                    errorsHtml += '<li>' + value[0] + '</li>';
                });
                errorsHtml += '</ul>';
               
            }
        }).always(function () {
        });
```